# Drag item into a specific place inside a list in Vue 3

Tags: drag-and-drop, vuejs3, drag

I am trying to create a dynamic board with lists where I can drag and drop items on those lists. Currently, I can drag and drop items between lists, however, whenever I move an item, it always appears at the end of the list. I would like to be able to drop items either at the top of the list or in between other list items. If possible, I would like to do this without downloading any external libraries.

Here is what I have:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="h-10 bg-netural2">
            <div
            @click="createList">
                new list
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="bg-white flex flex-row overflow-x-auto py-2 px-2 gap-2"
            :style='calculatedHeight'
        >
            <!--List-->
            <div 
                class="list bg-netural2 mb-1 align-expand flex flex-col rounded-sm" 
                v-for="lists in board.lists"
                @drop="onDrop( $event, lists.id)"
                @dragover="allowDrop($event)"
            >
                <div class="flex justify-between py-3 px-6 border-b-2">
                    <div>
                        <p class="truncate">List title</p>
                    </div>
                    <div @click="createCard( lists.id )">
                        Filler Content
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--DraggableArea-->
                <div class="py-3 px-3 bg-netural2 overflow-y-auto"
                    :style='dragableAreaHeight'
                >
                    <Task v-for="(item, index) in lists.cards"
                        :draggable="true"
                        @dragover.prevent
                        @dragstart="onDrag( $event, item )" 
                        :cardData="item"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import { v4 as uuid4 } from 'uuid'
    import Task from '@/components/subviews/boards/Task'
    export default {
        name: 'Board',
        components: {
            Task
        },
        data() {
            return {
                board: {
                    lists: []
                },
                barHeight: '144px',
                listID: '',
                list: {
                    title: 'Hello'
                },
                card: {
                    title: ''
                },
                currentCard: {},
                cardDraggedID: '',
                cardDraggedListID: '',
                dialog: false,
                dialogCard: false,
                dialogEditCard: false,
                drawer: false,
            }
        },
        computed: {
            calculatedHeight: function () {
                return `height: calc( 100vh - ${this.barHeight})`
            },
            dragableAreaHeight: function () {
                return `height: calc( 100% - 50px );`;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            createList: function () {
                const _this = this;
                if ( _this.list.title != '' ) {
                    _this.list.id = uuid4();
                    _this.list.cards = [];
                    _this.board.lists.push( _this.list); 
                } 
                this.list = {};
            },
            createCard: function ( updatedListID ) {
                this.listID = updatedListID;
                const _this = this;
                this.card.title = uuid4();
                if ( _this.card.title != '' ) {
                    _this.card.id = uuid4();
                    _this.card.listID = _this.listID;

                    let listToInsertInto = _this.board.lists.find( function ( list ) {
                        return list.id === _this.listID;
                    });
                    
                    if ( !listToInsertInto.cards ) {
                        listToInsertInto.cards = [];
                    } 
                    listToInsertInto.cards.push( _this.card );

                }
                this.card = {};
            },
            onDrag: function ( event, item ) {
                this.currentCard = item;
            },
            onDrop: function ( event, listID ){
                event.preventDefault();
                this.updateCardList( listID );
            },
            allowDrop: function ( event ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            },
            updateCardList( newListID ) {
                const _this = this;
                let listToInsertInto = _this.board.lists.find( function ( list ) {
                    return list.id === newListID;
                });

                let listToTakeCardFrom = _this.board.lists.find( function ( list ) {
                    return list.cards.find( function ( card ) {
                        return _this.currentCard.id === card.id;
                    });
                });

                listToTakeCardFrom.cards.splice( listToTakeCardFrom.cards.findIndex( function ( card ) {
                    return card.id === _this.currentCard.id;
                }), 1);

                if (!listToInsertInto.cards) {
                    listToInsertInto.cards = [];
                }

                listToInsertInto.cards.push( this.currentCard );
            } 
            
        }
    }
</script>
<style scoped>
    .list {
        min-width: 440px;
        width: 440px;
        max-width: 440px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Can you confirm whether the element is added to the listToInsertInto in the correct location?

Comment: @Fanoflix The element is added to `listToInsertInto` but right now it is only appended to the end of the list instead of between/above other elements